# Как ограничить видимость модели для пользователя?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Как сделать чтоб только создатель модели мог ее видеть, а другие участники ее не могли видеть?

у меня есть модель models.py

```
from django.db import models

from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser


USER_MODEL = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    spent = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Name: {self.username} id: {self.id}'


class TimeStampModel(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    deleted_at = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class RegiserModel(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username

class Product(models.Model):
    user = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/', blank=True, null=True)
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user

class Purchase(TimeStampModel):
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    product_id = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    amount = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    make_refund_status = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

views.py

```
class ProductListView(ListView):
    model = Product
    template_name = 'products_list.html'
    queryset = Product.objects.all()


class ProfileUser(LoginRequiredMixin,ListView):
    template_name = 'profile.html'
    queryset = CustomUser.objects.all()

class ProfileUserEdit(LoginRequiredMixin,UpdateView):
    template_name = 'profile_edit.html'
    model = CustomUser
    form_class = EditProfileUser
    success_url = reverse_lazy('product_list_page')
    queryset = CustomUser.objects.all()


class ProductDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Product


class NewProductView(LoginRequiredMixin,CreateView):
    template_name = 'product_form.html'
    model = Product
    form_class = NewProductForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('product_list_page')

class EditProductView(LoginRequiredMixin,UpdateView):
    template_name = 'product_form.html'
    model = Product
    form_class = EditProductForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('product_list_page')
```

Как ограничить видимость модели только для его создателя?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`django.contrib.auth.mixin` содержит класс `PermissionRequiredMixin`

Добавляете во вьюху его, указываете в `has_permission` методе доп условие на совпадение юзера.

```
class EditProductView(LoginRequiredMixin, PermissionRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    template_name = 'product_form.html'
    model = Product
    form_class = EditProductForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('product_list_page')

    def has_permission(self)
        has_perm = super().has_permission()
        obj = self.get_object()
        if not (obj.user and self.request.user.is_authenticated and obj.user.pk == self.request.user):
            return False
        return has_perm
```

Как то так

---

UPD:

```
class RegiserModel(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username

class Product(models.Model):
    user = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/', blank=True, null=True)
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user
```

Не знаю, зачем вам этот велосипед `RegiserModel`. В Django есть `django.contrib.auth.models.User` или `django.contrib.auth.get_user_model` на стандартную модель пользователя.

```
class Product(models.Model):
    user = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Свять с пользователем делают через `models.ForeignKey` где указывают модель, где хранятся данные пользователей. По строке искать не вариант, почему - другой вопрос, возможно гугл подскажет. Я ответить не могу, ибо не знаю всех целей вашего проекта.

В общем. Нужно провести рефакторинг кода. Если лень - то в ниже код для вашего варианта

```
    def has_permission(self)
        has_perm = super().has_permission()
        obj = self.get_object()
        if not (self.request.is_authenticated and obj.user == self.request.user.username):
            return False
        return has_perm
```

Comment: привет , я не особо понял как это правильно написать , можем где -то в телеграмме допустим списаться чтоб ты более лучше обьяснил, буду очень благодарен

Comment: я добавил модели и вьюху от этого твой вариант измениться или нет ? я не особо понял как им правильно воспользоваться

Comment: обновил ответ под ваши нужды

Comment: спасибо большое, я понял